# Case statement in Oracle for selecting single row

Tags: oracle, case

I have a table 'tblA' with the following data:

```
wuser_id wcompleted wstatusdate
123      1          10212014
123      0          11212014
456      0          02222014
456      0          03122014
```

I want to select wstatusdate for wuser_id '123' based on wcompleted, when wcompleted is 1 then I need to select '10212014' only, 
for '456' when wcompleted is 0 then I need to select '03122014' only. My below query is returning two rows for the user_is 123.

Below is what I am doing,

```
select distinct wuser_id,
case wcompleted 
when 1
then max(wstatusdate)
when 0
then max(wstatusdate) 
end  
from tblA 
group by wuser_id, wcompleted
```

Results:

```
wuser_id wstatusdate
123      10212014
123      11212014
456      03122014
```

I need the result to be:

```
wuser_id wstatusdate
123      10212014
456      03122014
```

Comment: What is the datatype of wstatusdate?

Comment: Datatype for wstatusdate is 'Date'. I need to select only one row if wcompleted is 1

Comment: You need to check your group by.  
`123 0` and  
`123 1`  
are different

Comment: Thanks Nitish, would you know how to form the correct statement for my query? If wcompleted = 1 is found then ignore all other rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like the following:

```
SELECT wuser_id, wcompleted, wstatusdate FROM (
    SELECT wuser_id, wcompleted, wstatusdate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY wuser_id ORDER BY wcompleted DESC, wstatusdate DESC ) AS rn
      FROM tblA
) WHERE rn = 1;
```

or you could do the following:

```
SELECT wuser_id, MAX(wcompleted) AS wcompleted
     , MAX(wstatusdate) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY wcompleted DESC) AS wstatusdate
  FROM tblA
 GROUP BY wuser_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the analytic function row_number to assign a row number to each row. Once you have that, you can then put that in a subquery and select the 1st row. Here's something to get you started:

```
with tbla as (select 123 wuser_id, 1 wcompleted, to_date('10212014', 'mmddyyyy') wstatusdate from dual union all
              select 123 wuser_id, 0 wcompleted, to_date('11212014', 'mmddyyyy') wstatusdate from dual union all
              select 789 wuser_id, 1 wcompleted, to_date('10212014', 'mmddyyyy') wstatusdate from dual union all
              select 789 wuser_id, 1 wcompleted, to_date('12212014', 'mmddyyyy') wstatusdate from dual union all
              select 789 wuser_id, 0 wcompleted, to_date('11212014', 'mmddyyyy') wstatusdate from dual union all
              select 456 wuser_id, 0 wcompleted, to_date('02222014', 'mmddyyyy') wstatusdate from dual union all
              select 456 wuser_id, 0 wcompleted, to_date('03122014', 'mmddyyyy') wstatusdate from dual)
-- end of mimicking your tbla table.
select wuser_id,
       wcompleted,
       wstatusdate,
       row_number() over (partition by wuser_id
                          order by wcompleted desc, wstatusdate desc) rn
from   tbla;

  WUSER_ID WCOMPLETED WSTATUSDATE         RN
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------
       123          1 21-OCT-14            1
       123          0 21-NOV-14            2
       456          0 12-MAR-14            1
       456          0 22-FEB-14            2
       789          1 21-DEC-14            1
       789          1 21-OCT-14            2
       789          0 21-NOV-14            3
```